# angularjs: compare values in Array, and add the amount of it in an new array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sorting, compare

I have an Array with several values, and I want to compare if some values are equal to each other and if there is more then 1 equal of it then put the values in an new array

Example:

```
   for(var i=0; i<res.data.diaries.length;i++){

        var values = res.data.diaries[i].diary.symptoms;
        if( typeof values.whichSymptoms !== 'undefined' ) {
            // foo could get resolved and it's defined
            for(var j= 0; j<values.whichSymptoms.length;j++){
                //console.log(values.whichSymptoms[j].text);
                var whichSymptoms = values.whichSymptoms[j];
                console.log(whichSymptoms);

                //// ToDo Check values if equal and put that in an array.
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the array, and a sample of the desired output?

Comment: Example: output Array = [a,b,a,b,c,d,a,a,b,c,e,f,g,e]; new Array2 = [a,a,a,a], we have 4 a ... new Array3 = [b,b,b]... 3 b ... etc.

Comment: Is there a "field" name that holds the values?  Like Array =[{name:a}, {name:b}]?

Comment: Ok, maybe I try to explain it again... I have an Array, this array called whichSymptoms... some values of this array are equal... I want to iterate the equal values and push these in an array to count it... how often is value a and b and c

Comment: Return the number of times a value occurs in a given array... array[{name:'a'},{name:'b'},{name:'c'},{name:'a'}]....how often is 'name' with the value a?, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, got it now...
        var counts = {};
        var element;
        myArray.forEach(function(element) {
            counts[element] = (counts[element] || 0) + 1;
        });
        var donatSymptoms =[];
        var donatSymptomsCount =[];
        for ( element in counts) {
            donatSymptoms.push(element);
            donatSymptomsCount.push(counts[element])
            console.log(element + ' = ' + counts[element]);
        }
        console.log(donatSymptoms,donatSymptomsCount);